# asterisk: command not found

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to run the following script...

```
#!/bin/bash -x
ADMIN=..@.com

X='asterisk -rx "show channels" | grep -c Zap/'
if [$X -ge 4]; then
echo "Active Calls: $X" |
mail -s "Active Calls: $X" $ADMIN
fi
```

and get this error "**line 5: [asterisk: command not found**"

I'm really new to this but understand it's probably a path problem. However from the same directory that I'm running the script from I can type out the 'asterisk -rx "show cha...' command and it works fine. So don't understand why the shell script can't do the same? Thanks!

Comment: Is the script running in a cron job, or otherwise as a different user than you at the console?

Comment: No, I'm running the script from the console, same user as when I run the asterisk -rx command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold

1. This line: `X='asterisk -rx "show
   channels" | grep -c Zap/'`.  You
   want to use command substitution for
   this via `$()`
2. This line: `if [$X -ge 4]; then`. The `[` is actually not syntax but a call to a binary named `[` which is the same as the `test` binary.  Therefor you *must* put a space after the `[` otherwise the shell will complain as you have seen.

.

```
#!/bin/sh -x
ADMIN="..@.com" # don't forget to quote this

X=$(asterisk -rx "show channels" | grep -c Zap/)
if [ "$X" -ge 4 ]; then # don't forget the spaces
  echo "Active Calls: $X" |
  mail -s "Active Calls: $X" $ADMIN
fi
```

Note that if you are going to use `bash` you might as well use its nicer syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
ADMIN="..@.com" # don't forget to quote this

X=$(asterisk -rx "show channels" | grep -c Zap/)
if ((X > 4)); then # much nicer syntax
  echo "Active Calls: $X" |
  mail -s "Active Calls: $X" $ADMIN
fi
```

Comment: DAMN you are good and fast! LOL, that worked great. Thank you VERY much!